# Build url to navigate user to the Uber map

Tags: javascript, html, uber-api

I have the google map on my site. I display there direction from the point A to the point B for user. I want to add Uber integration to my site. There should be an 'Uber' button and when user clicks this button he will be navigated to the Uber's map with pre-filled pick up and drop off points. What is the proper way to do it? I have lat & lng for points A and B. I build this link following way:

var link= 'https://m.uber.com/ul?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&pickup=' + currentLocation.lat + '&pickup=' + currentLocation.lng + '&product_id=db6779d6-d8da-479f-8ac7-8068f4dade6f&dropoff=' + destinationLocation.lat + '&dropoff=' + destinationLocation.lat;

So the real link looks like this:

https://m.uber.com/ul?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&pickup=55.1777478&pickup=61.333037399999995&product_id=db6779d6-d8da-479f-8ac7-8068f4dade6f&dropoff=55.15325199999999&dropoff=55.15325199999999   (instead of the "MY_CLIENT_ID" I use real client ID)

My problem is that when I clicks on this link, uber navigates me to the Uber's sign up form (I already have uber's account and I was logged in to the uber on my computer. And if I fill in the form with my credentials uber says that "This email has already been registered. Sign into your existing account, or register with a different email.").

Ideally I want to be navigated to this page:

[image]

Could you please consult me is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

`https://m.uber.com/ul` is an endpoint for Uber's deep linking. It's purpose is to open Uber mobile app when clicked from  a web-browser on a mobile device.

The sign-up form redirection is a normal response for any request to this endpoint from a desktop browser as stated in the API documentation:

> When a user taps taps an universal link:
>
> - If the Uber app is installed on the device, the user will be deep
>     linked into the app
> - If the Uber app is not installed and the user is
>     on iOS or Android, the user will be directed to the App Store or
>     Google Play Store to download Uber
> - On all other devices, the user will
>     be redirected to the Uber account sign-up page:
>     https://m.uber.com/sign-up

Source: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/deep-linking-universal-links

**Edit:**

Another thing I should probably point out is a format of coordinates in a request:

m.uber.com/ul?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818

(Notice *[latitude]* and *[longitude]* specificators)

Source: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/deep-linking-action-setpickup